# Disable button until user clicks on a record on a Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

I have a gridpanel, and underneath it when i click on a row (record) of the grid, and i click on the button a window appears.

But what i want to do is to **disable** the button **unless** the user clicks on a record (a row) of the Grid.

How can i do this ?

I am using Sencha-Architech 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use the grid's [selectionchange](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-selectionchange) event:

> Fired after a selection change has occurred

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TkZsm/

Comment: Ok, but how can i activate the button when the event is fired.

Comment: @sharonHwk: `button.setDisabled(false);`